# Can't install SMSS 2016 March Preview

Tags: installation, sql

I am trying to install the latest Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio release. This is what the installation log looks like just before the installation fails:

```
[44C4:4610][2016-04-03T23:15:57]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Started for package Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) - 14.0.23026
[44C4:4610][2016-04-03T23:15:57]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 0, Overall progress: 0
[4588:0838][2016-04-03T23:15:57]i301: Applying execute package: VCRedistD14x86, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\BFB74E498C44D3A103CA3AA2831763FB417134D1\redist\VC_redist.x86.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\BFB74E498C44D3A103CA3AA2831763FB417134D1\redist\VC_redist.x86.exe" /q /norestart /log %localappdata%\temp\SsmsSetup\VCRedistD14'
[44C4:4610][2016-04-03T23:15:57]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 50, Overall progress: 1
[44C4:4610][2016-04-03T23:15:58]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 50, Overall progress: 1
[44C4:4610][2016-04-03T23:15:58]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 50, Overall progress: 1
[4588:0838][2016-04-03T23:15:58]e000: Error 0x80070666: Process returned error: 0x666
[4588:0838][2016-04-03T23:15:58]e000: Error 0x80070666: Failed to execute EXE package.
[44C4:4610][2016-04-03T23:15:58]e000: Error 0x80070666: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[44C4:4610][2016-04-03T23:15:58]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Completed for package Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) - 14.0.23026
[44C4:4610][2016-04-03T23:15:58]i319: Applied execute package: VCRedistD14x86, result: 0x80070666, restart: None
[44C4:4610][2016-04-03T23:15:58]e000: Error 0x80070666: Failed to execute EXE package.
[4588:0838][2016-04-03T23:15:58]i351: Removing cached package: VCRedistD14x86, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\BFB74E498C44D3A103CA3AA2831763FB417134D1\
[44C4:4610][2016-04-03T23:15:58]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 100, Overall progress: 100
[4588:0838][2016-04-03T23:15:58]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {b71b5744-181f-40a1-9834-6f79771f5336}
[4588:0838][2016-04-03T23:15:58]i352: Removing cached bundle: {b71b5744-181f-40a1-9834-6f79771f5336}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{b71b5744-181f-40a1-9834-6f79771f5336}\
[44C4:4610][2016-04-03T23:15:58]e000: MainViewModel.OnBundleAction: Bundle action failed
[44C4:4610][2016-04-03T23:15:58]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070666, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[44C4:43C0][2016-04-03T23:16:21]i000: MainViewModel.OpenUrl: Opening url: C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Local\Temp\SsmsSetup\SSMS-Setup-ENU_20160403231514.log
```

I don't know what the "Process returned error 0x666" means.

This may or may not be the problem, but I noticed that my SQL Server 2016 installation does not match the SMSS installation version. Does the SMSS software need to match the version of SQL Server 2016 that is installed on my PC? If so, what would be the best way to upgrade SQL Server 2016? I'm afraid if I upgrade then it may break Visual Studio or something else that depends on it. It seems like there is no way to download older versions of SMSS either (for SMSS 2016 anyway).

Answer (score 2):

C++ redistributable 12.0.23026 seems to have a problem if 14.0.23506 is installed already.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2549809/ssms-march-2016-preview-fails-to-install-if-a-higher-version-of-visual-c-redistributable-x86-is-installed

I was able to uninstall 23506 via add/remove programs.  March 2016 preview installed just fine. I then reinstalled the 23506 from microsofts download site.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Comment: Microsoft posted a workaround on April 7 at your first link that is easier than uninstalling/reinstalling VC++. Also, this bug will be fixed in the next release of SSMS 2016.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Dave Melton worked for me except that the link to 23506 was actually to 23026. The link to download 14.0.23506 is here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49984

> I was able to uninstall 23506 via add/remove programs. March 2016 preview installed just fine. I then reinstalled the 23506 from microsofts download site. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145